# Pyinstaller .exe cannot use module with __file__

Tags: python, file, module, pyinstaller

guys! I have a question and need your help!

The question: I have a main Python script named **client.py** and in it, I import a module called **stata_setup.config**. But there is a **if statements** in **config.py** to judge whether the directory of **`__file__`** is right, so after pyinstaller, when I run the **client.exe**, it always raise error:***"failed to load Stata's shared library"***. The error and the related codes in **config.py** are as follows:

```
def _get_st_home():
pypath = os.path.normpath(os.path.abspath(__file__))
d_utilities = dirname(dirname(pypath))

if os.path.basename(d_utilities).lower()=="utilities":
    return dirname(d_utilities)
else:
    _RaiseSystemException("failed to load Stata's shared library")
```

The reason: After searching and learning, I know it's because that the pyinstaller's bootloader changes original directory.

Can anyone please help me? I know the reason, but I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this method:
 `if os.path.isfile('./stata_setup.config'):`. the '.' looks for the file if its in the same directory as the script. if you file is in a folder then it'd look like this
 `if os.path.isfile('./folder/stata_setup.config')`.
for what ever reason pyinstaller doesn't like using `(__file__)`

Comment: Thanks! I solved this in another way with a server! :-)